# How to open chromium with half of screen-width and aligned to right screen-border?

Tags: node.js, chromium, browser-testing, taiko

I would like to set the window-position within the total available screen, so it takes up half of the screen-size and is positioned at the right end of the screen with its right border. Couldn't find any docs about it, maybe it's not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [docs state](https://docs.taiko.dev/api/openbrowser/), the `args`-option of `openBrowser()` accepts all of the [Chromium browser launch options](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) and the nodejs-package "robotjs" helps to get the screen-size. Also "screenres" claims to able to do that, but I haven't tested it.

This opens the browser-window with half of the screen-width, and positions it to be right-aligned within the screen:

```
const { closeBrowser, openBrowser } = require('taiko')

const screenSize = require('robotjs').getScreenSize()

const screenWidth = screenSize.width / 2

const screenHeight = screenSize.height

const windowSize = '--window-size=' + screenWidth + ',' + screenHeight

const windowPosition = '--window-position=' + screenWidth + ',0'


async () => {

  try {
       
    await openBrowser({ args: [ windowPosition, windowSize ] })

  } catch (error) {

    console.error(error);

  } finally {

    await closeBrowser();

  }

})();
```